# Accessing a MVC 4 database using ADO.net

Tags: android, database, asp.net-mvc-4, web-applications, ado.net

I have developed a C# MVC 4 internet application and have a question relating to accessing this database using ADO.net.

Is this possible? Is this easy?

I am wishing to access the database from an Android application.

May I please have some help/advice

Thanks in advance